# AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'create_alarm'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

I have a topic with name "topic" that I want to monitor with cloudwatch.

And using cloudwatch, I want that when this topic "topic" have NumberOfMessagesPublished > 100 I want to send a notification to other topic with name "cloudwatchSNS".

Im trying to do this with code below, but Im having this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'create_alarm'
```

Can you give me a help put this working correctly?

```
import boto.sns
from boto.ec2.cloudwatch import MetricAlarm
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch

sns = boto.sns.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
cloudwatch = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region("us-east-1")

#topic to send notification when NumberOfMessagesPublished > 100
topicToSendNotification = sns.create_topic("cloudwatchSNS")

topicArnToSendNotification = topicarn['CreateTopicResponse']['CreateTopicResult']['TopicArn']

#topicName to control the number of messages published
topicNameToMonitor = "topic"

#subscriptor in topic to receive an email when NumberOfMessagesPublished > 100
subscription = sns.subscribe(topicArnToSendNotification, "email", "mail@mail.com")

metric = cloudwatch.list_metrics(dimensions={'TopicName':topicNameToMonitor},
                         metric_name="NumberOfMessagesPublished")

alarmName = "test"

metric.create_alarm(name=alarmName, comparison='>=', threshold=100, period=300,
                    evaluation_periods=2, statistic='Average', alarm_actions=[topicarnToSendNotification])
```

Comment: You should post the complete traceback of the error and tag the code line (using an easy to identify comment or so) of the error. The message posted so far just states the object does not have the required attribute (hear hear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `cloud watch.list_metrics(...)` will always return a list-like object called a `ResultSet`, even if there is only 1 result.  You need to get the actual `Metric` object out of the list before trying to create an alarm on it.

```
metric = cloudwatch.list_metrics(dimensions={'TopicName':topicNameToMonitor},
                     metric_name="NumberOfMessagesPublished")[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with your solution Im getting this "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Well, then the call to ``list_metrics`` must not be returning any results.  Try inspecting the ResultSet to see what it contains.  Are you certain you have the ``TopicName`` correct?

Comment: Yes the topic name "topic" is correct and appear in aws managment console in SNS. However  this topic name "topic" dont appear in cloudwatch managment console in cloudwatch sns metrics...but I dont understand why. But this should be the issue. Because in dimensions if I use a topicName that appear in aws cloudwatch managment console it works...

Comment: Have you actually used the topic yet?  I don't think the name will appear in CloudWatch until actual metrics exist for the topic.

Comment: No, I havent used the topic yet. Its necessary to use the topic first, and only after use it its possible to create a cloudwatch alarm?

Comment: If you haven't used the topic then no metrics would have been gathered for the topic and nothing would be available in CloudWatch.